# Verify that the JWT contains three segments, separated by two period ('.') characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a token and I would like to verify its format. Token is split in three part and separated by two periods. How I could verify in Ruby that format is correct?

```
EdU9nPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiIxZTc5NGJhMS04MjU3LLnVrIn0.H47WxkrCrAFGAvznwjPfjXEaG
```

Comment: Via the [JWT](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) gem?

Comment: I catch token in Authorization headers and I need to make sure in headers I have token and not something else

Comment: A string with 2 dots in it isn't necessarily a (valid) token. The gem can validate the token on different levels – number of segments, whether the segments can be decoded and last not least if the token's signature is valid. There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F) with a regular expression. This avoids the creation of a temporary array, such as when `String#split` is used.

```
def three_parts?(token)
  token.match?(/\A[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\z/)
end
```

```
three_parts?('ab.cd.ef') #=> true
three_parts?('abc.def')  #=> false
three_parts?('a.bd.e.f') #=> false
three_parts?('.abc.def') #=> false
three_parts?('abc.def.') #=> false
three_parts?('abc..def') #=> false
three_parts?('..')       #=> false
```

The regular expression can be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*:

```
/
\A      # match beginning of string
[^.]+   # match 1+ '.'
\.      # match '.'
[^.]+   # match 1+ '.'  
\.      # match '.'
[^.]+   # match 1+ '.'
\z      # match end of string
/x      # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

The regex can alternatively be written

```
/
\A      # match beginning of string
[^.]+   # match 1+ '.'
(?:     # begin non-capture group
  \.    # match '.'
  [^.]+ # match 1+ '.'
)       # end non-capture group  
{2}     # execute non-capture group 2 times
\z      # match end of string
/x      # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

The latter (`/\A[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+){2}\z/`) would be useful if more than three parts were required. If `n` parts were required, one could simply replace `2` in `{2}` with `n-1`.

`String#match` made its debut in Ruby v2.4. To support earlier versions one could write

```
  !!token.match(/\A[^.]+\.[^.]+[^.]+/)
```

or

```
  !!(token =~ /\A[^.]+\.[^.]+[^.]+/)
```

`!!` is a trick to convert truthy/falsy values to `true/false`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not talking about decoding the JWT, just making sure it's three dot-separated parts, you could just do...

```
token.split('.').count == 3
```

Comment: Cheers, I have added to your answer token.count(".") == 2 to check that token has two periods and three segments

Comment: `'.abc.def'.split('.').count == 3 #=> true`, `'abc.def.'.split('.').count == 3 #=> false` and `'..abc'.split('.').count == 3 #=> true`. AutoVit, is that what you want?,

Answer (score 0):

Based on Steve Turczyn answer I check that token contains three segments and two periods.

```
 token.split('.').count == 3 && token.count(".") == 2
```